# Remove label in view Swift5

Tags: ios, swift, uiview, uilabel, nslayoutconstraint

I'm adding a label programatically in my view, in viewDidAppear:

```
var label : UILabel!

override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
    super.viewDidAppear(animated)
  ...........

      label = UILabel(frame: CGRect(x: 0,y: 0, width: 200, height: 40))
        label.numberOfLines=2
        label.textAlignment = .center
        label.attributedText = amountText
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        
        
        self.view.addSubview(label)
        constrains1 = NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .bottom, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: bottomLayoutGuide, attribute: .top, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        constrains2 =  NSLayoutConstraint(item: label, attribute: .right, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: view, attribute: .right, multiplier: 1, constant: 0);
        view.addConstraints([constrains1,constrains2])
  ............
```

This label has to be removed after purchase, but not work:

```
func buy(alert: UIAlertAction!) {
    
    self.view.setNeedsLayout()
    self.showSpinner(onView: self.view)
    
    SwiftyStoreKit.purchaseProduct("com...........", quantity: 1, atomically: true) { result in
        
        switch result {
        case .success(let purchase):                
            DispatchQueue.global(qos: .background).async {
                
                DispatchQueue.main.async {
                    print("buy: \(purchase.productId)")
                    
                    self.label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
                    self.label.isHidden = true;

                    
                    self.view.addConstraint(NSLayoutConstraint(item: self.label, attribute: .height, relatedBy: .equal, toItem: nil, attribute: .notAnAttribute, multiplier: 1.0, constant: 0))
                    
                    self.view.needsUpdateConstraints()
                    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
                    self.removeSpinner()
                }
                
            }
```

I try removeFromSuperview, change color, change text...but nothing change label visibility.

What is the error??
Thanks a lot

Comment: show the code where you declare `label` ?

Comment: Hello! Now I have added the declaration in the question. Thank you

Comment: Does viewDidAppear get called more than once because each time it will add a new label and only the last one will get removed/hidden.  For example do you navigate to another view and back again.

Comment: @UpholderOfTruth :facepalm This is the problem. Multiple tags were added. I have modified the code so that it is only added once. Thanks for the help!

Comment: No worries, glad I could help.